# How to Derive Gibbs Sampling Update Formula for Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: markov-chains, bayesian-network, gibbs-measure

I want to understand how to derive the update formula for Gibbs sampling for Hidden Markov Model, for example, in [here](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v31/wang13b.pdf):

> $$p(z_t | \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t}, \boldsymbol{\alpha},
> > \boldsymbol\beta) \propto \dfrac{C_{x_t, z_t}^{-t} + \beta}{\sum_x
> > C_{x, z_t}^{-t} + W\beta} \dfrac{C_{z_t, z_{t-1}}^{-t} +
> > \alpha}{\sum_z C_{z, z_{t-1}} + K\alpha} \dfrac{C_{z_{t+1}, z_t}^{-t}
> > + \alpha + \delta(z_{t-1} = z_t = z_{t+1})}{\sum_{z}C_{z, z_t}^{-t} + K\alpha + \delta(z_{t-1} = z_t)},$$
>
> - $z_t \in \{1, \cdots, K\}$ is a hidden state,
> - $x_t \in \{1,
>   > \cdots, W\}$ is an observed variable,
> - $p(x_t | z_t, \Phi) = p(x_t | \phi_{z_t}) = \phi_{x_t, z_t}$ -
>     emission probability;
> - $p(z_t | z_{t-1}, \Xi) = p(z_t | \xi_{z_{t-1}}) = \xi_{z_t, z_{t-1}}$
>     transition probability;
> - $\phi_z \sim Dir(\phi_z; \boldsymbol\beta)$ - the prior distribution
>     for the emission probability is Dirichlet with the symmetric
>     hyper-parameter $\boldsymbol\beta$;
> - $\xi_z \sim Dir(\xi_z; \boldsymbol\alpha)$ - the prior distribution
>     for the transition probability is Dirichlet with the symmetric
>     hyper-parameter $\boldsymbol\alpha$;
> - $C_{x, z}^{-t}$ - the number of times the observed variable $x$
>     associated to the state $z$, excluding the pair at the time moment
>     $t$;
> - $C_{z', z}^{-t}$ - the number of times the state $z$ was followed by
>     the state $z$ excluding the state at the time moment $t$

**The question is how to derive the second and third term from the formula?**

I think I can derive it from this relation:
$$\int p(z_{t+1} | z_t, \Xi) p(z_t | z_{t-1}, \Xi) p(\Xi | \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t}) \mathrm{d}\Xi$$ 
(similar to the derivation of the first term if considering different cases when $z_t = z_{t-1} = z_{t+1}, z_t \neq z_{t-1}$ and so on)

This derivation is possible **if** $p(\Xi | \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t})$ is Dirichlet, which is not obvious for me, as we have time dependency in the sequence of $z$, and we can't just ignore $z_t$ as $z_{t+1}$ depend on it. **Is it still true that the posterior of $\Xi$ is Dirichlet even though we throw $z_t$ away?**

**And how can we arrive at $\int p(z_{t+1} | z_t, \Xi) p(z_t | z_{t-1}, \Xi) p(\Xi | \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t}) \mathrm{d}\Xi$?**

Or is my train of thought wrong and there is another way to get the formula?

Any idea and suggestions will be very much appreciated.

---

**Context:**
The first term from the formula is easy to get:
$$p(z_t | \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t}, \boldsymbol\alpha, \boldsymbol\beta) \propto p(x_t | z_t, \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t}, \mathbf{x}_{\setminus t}, \boldsymbol\alpha, \boldsymbol\beta) p(z_t | \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t}, \mathbf{x}_{\setminus t}, \boldsymbol\alpha, \boldsymbol\beta)$$

The first term from here:
$$p(x_t | z_t, \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t}, \mathbf{x}_{\setminus t}, \boldsymbol\alpha, \boldsymbol\beta) = \int p(x_t | \Phi, z_t) p(\Phi | \mathbf{z}_{\setminus t}, \mathbf{x}_{\setminus t}, \boldsymbol\beta) \mathrm{d}\Phi$$

As the Dirichlet distribution is conjugate for the multinomial one, the second term under the integral is the Dirichlet distribution and the integral is the expected value for $\phi_{x_t, z_t}$ which is equal to the first term of the formula.